# MongoDB Connections Increasing, Even though i have disconnected all my resources from mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, connection, backend

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPRXW.png)

I have been using mongo db as my database , suddenly mongo db mails me that i have used maximum connection i.e 500 but i have only connected to a single application which iam working. even after stopping my api and mongo compass it shows some kind of random active connections , how to reduce the active connections to actual active connection??

Comment: Have you whitelisted only the IP addresses that you use?

Comment: Yes @semperlabs

Answer (score 0):

There are only few things to solve it.

Need to add the below options in your Mongo URI,

- connectTimeoutMS
- socketTimeoutMS
- maxIdleTimeMS

For my Case I have configured with below number

`<mongo_uri>?retryWrites=true&w=majority&maxIdleTimeMS=60000&connectTimeoutMS=150000&socketTimeoutMS=90000`

With these options i have solved the issue.